# Adapt old AvermediaTV DVB-T tuner as SDR

Tags: rtl-sdr, sdrsharp

I want to adapt the DVB-T AverMedia TV Pilot" tuner as a software defined radio, but it is not built on a RTL chip, so the question arises, is there some kind of driver to use my tuner as a radio?[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Does [this webpage](https://gamevid.ru/en/obzory/sdr-priemnik-iz-tv-tyunera-avermedia-portativnyi-dvb-t-tyuner-na-rtl2832-slushayu-efir/) describe what you have?

Comment: Yes, but I have an older tuner and it is built on a different chip.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not. Looking at the chips:

NXP TDA18271HDC2 is the RF frontend / "tuner" chip.

Afatech AF9033B is the DVB-T demodulator.

Conexant CX23102 is the analog TV demodulator.

NEC (now Renesas) uPD720114 is a USB hub, which shares the USB port between the AF9033B and the CX23102.

Neither the AF9033B nor the CX23102 seems to have a feature to directly sample the IF signal reaching it, the way the RTL2832 does, so there's no SDR potential here. It's a perfectly good TV receiver, but an entirely "fixed-function" one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It's just that this tuner has a GPS receiver, so I thought that I could make a sdr. I also heard that in the standard program for the receiver you can find a file where the frequency of its tuning is registered, and by opening this file in a notepad, you can correct the frequency to the desired one. I kind of went through all the files, but I couldn't find anything like that.